# Unable to print Error toast message

Tags: lightning-web-components, toast

Hope you're doing well.

I want to print an error toast, the pop-up appearing but the message is not printing.

I researched and tried a lot about that but was unsuccessful.

Below is my JS controller.

```
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
handleTimesheet() {
    saveData({
        firstName :this.firstName,
        lastName :this.lastName,
        accountId :this.recordId
    })
    .then(result => {
        //Shows Success Toast Event
        const e = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: result,
            variant: 'success',
            mode: 'dismissable',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(e);
        // console.log('result: ' +result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        //Shows Error Toast Event
        const e = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error Occured',
            message: error.body.message,
            // I TRIED THIS AND THE BELOW LINE AS WELL
            message: error.body.output.errors[0].message,
            // I GOT ERROR ON THIS LINE "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')"
            variant: 'error',
            mode: 'dismissable',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(e);
        console.log('Error: ', JSON.stringify(error));
    })
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `message: err.message`?

Comment: err not defined and toast pop-up is also not appearing

Comment: Sorry I meant `message: error.message`

Comment: yes, I tried it first. it doesn't show message on error toast. And I tried ```message: error``` as well.

Comment: Do the console.log messages give the expected output?

Comment: Yes Victor, console.log gives expected message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem after doing some research.

Just created another class for Custom Exception and used that custom exception in my main apex classes methods. Below i have pasted the link

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_custom.htm

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start, as Victor Lockwood suggests, is to also output to the JavaScript console to see what sort of data you are getting in your `error` variable:

```
.catch(error => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    ...
```

Looking at e.g. [reduceErrors](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsUtils/ldsUtils.js) referenced in the [Handle Server Errors](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-and-salesforce-data/handle-server-errors?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components) Trailhead there are quite a few possibilities; you could consider re-using that code if your case matches one of those.

(Unfortunately the simple "catch all" approach of using `JSON.stringify(error)` as the toast message typically fails because the JSON curly braces are interpreted as formatting delimiters - the `{0}` style ones - and that means most of the content isn't rendered.)